# ¿Debo usar "nos vemos el lunes donde tendremos..." o "nos vemos el lunes cuando tendremos..."?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

¿Cuál de estas dos formas es correcta?

> Nos vemos el próximo lunes **donde** tendremos una interesante entrevista con la directora de educación.

o

> Nos vemos el próximo lunes **cuando** tendremos una interesante entrevista con la directora de educación.

Comment: No es el lugar correcto para usar el cuando o donde. El "donde" presenta o describe un lugar y el "cuando" anuncia tiempo. Fuera de que se entiende lo que tratas de decir yo lo pondría como: "Nos vemos el próximo lunes. Como parte del día tendremos una interesante entrevista con la directora de educación. "

Answer (score 5):

`Donde` es un adverbio de **lugar**, mientras que `cuando` es un adverbio de `tiempo`. `Cuando` puede ser usado también como conjunción temporal, por lo que dado tu ejemplo puede ser correcto usar el `cuando` (forzando el significado de "y entonces"), aunque no es del todo placentero al oído.

Sería del todo correcto decir

> Nos vemos el próximo lunes CUANDO **tengamos** la entrevista con la directora de educación.  <sub>Nos veremos porque temos la entrevista</sub>

No deberías usar el `donde`, ya que no te estás refiriendo a un lugar geográfico, sino a un lugar "temporal".